# Check Username is in database php & get data from two tables to login

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, multiple-users

I am creating a website where there are three different levels of access

- 0 = normal
- 1 = staff
- 2 = admin

In the login form, I managed to check if the password(SHA1) matches the one in the database (which is encrypted), but didn't check the user id.

When the user or staff / admin are registered, their details are stored into
separate tables which have more details( Name, DateOfBirth, ... ).

## Questions

1. how would I implement this in my code?

   ```
   $result = mysql_query( $qs ) or die( mysql_error() );
   while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
       $stored_password = $row['Password'];
       if( $stored_password == sha1( $pw ) ){
           $_SESSION['Status'] = $row['Status'];
       if( $_SESSION['Status'] == 0 ){
           echo "<h1>User Menu Loading...</h1>";
           echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='1;URL=http://***/'>";
       }else{
           echo "<h1>Incorrect Password.</h1>";
           echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='1;URL=http://**/login.php'>";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Is there a way all these three types of users can login via the login page and can retrieve the data from two different tables?

I have tried many ways but keep getting a blank screen or it says

> incorrect password

even though the password is correct.

**variables**

```
$un = $_POST['User_ID'];
$sf = $_POST['Staff_ID'];
$pw = $_POST['Password'];
$st = $_POST['Status'];
```

if not then I think I should create separate login areas.

thank you ( **I am currently changing mysql to mysqli** )

## EDIT

ADDED **MOST RECENT TRY** OF *$qs*

```
$qs="SELECT Cadets.Cadet_ID, Cadets.Password, Cadets.Status, 
        Staff.Staff_ID, Staff.Password, Staff.Status, 
 FROM   Cadets, Staff
 WHERE  Cadets.Cadet_ID ='$un' AND Staff.Staff_ID = '$sf'";
```

Comment: you should include your database structure or some query

Comment: please update the question with the value of `$qs` (the query you are using right now)

Comment: @bg17aw done - added my most recent try of it. thanks and sorry

Comment: @Veej, I think that $qs is the one you use for question no 2. You should also include the $qs you use for question no 1.

Comment: You should also provide the database structure, or at least explain it better.

Comment: @Trix Thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll update my answer as you edit your question to include more info.

A) You should not use the mysql library, as it is insecure and deprecated (soon to be removed): [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) 
You should use mysqli or PDO library.

B) sha1 is not secure, you should use something like [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) but I guess sha1 is fine for educational purposes.

C) Question 1: You don't need to check for the ID.
You use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` but since you are looking for a unique username/combination, there should only be one result or none:

```
if ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

You seem to be only checking if the password is correct, but you should really be checking for a unique combination of username AND password (what if two users have the same passwords? `sha1()` is not helping you there.

So you should have something like:

```
$qs = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '" . sha1($pw) ."'"
```

Or if you use the actual staff ID as the username:

$qs = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$id' AND password = '" . sha1($pw) ."'"

D) You won't be able to see this message `echo "<h1>User Menu Loading...</h1>";` as you have a redirect immediately after

E) Question 2: you need to clarify a bit more, are there 2 or 3 tables (since you mention there are 3 types of users).

Comment: Hey so i talked to my teacher about the issue and he did say i should just us a user table as well, as that was help solve the problem - this was the $qs would be selecting username, password and status from the user table not trying to look for it from two different tables                                                       He also mentioned that if possible I should change the sha1 and I had read your answer earlier so i told him about crypt and he said thats fine                             Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Q.1) **To check the user id**: First check the userid in the database and then check for password

```
$db=new mysqli("host", "sqlusername","sqlpassword","database");
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from your_table_name where user_ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$un);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
```

Q.2) **Yes. There is a way to do so. But question is a bit incomplete add some codes.**